# A suspended hyphen in a list with only one hyphenated word

Tags: punctuation, lists, parallelism, suspended-hyphen, list-order

Consider the list:

> experimental economics, behavioral economics, cognitive economics, evolutionary economics, and neuroeconomics.

Well, I am editing a submission with the above list rendered by the author as:

> experimental, behavioral, cognitive, evolutionary, and neuroeconomics.

I don't like that. But, I thought, "neuroeconomics" is also acceptable as the hyphenated "neuro-economics." So I wrote out this as a possible alternative:

> experimental, behavioral, cognitive, evolutionary, and neuro- economics.

Anyone think that's a reasonable solution?

Comment: ***Neuroeconomics*** is a new one on me, but according to Wikipedia it [*combines research methods from neuroscience, experimental and behavioral economics, and cognitive and social psychology.*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuroeconomics) So why not just write *"Neuroeconomics (including experimental, behavioral, cognitive, and evolutionary economics and psychology)"*. I doubt it's worth bothering about exactly which of those words are sub-genres of *economics*, and which are *psychology*).

Comment: No, neuroeconomics does not contain the others, and as editor of an economics journal, I think that's worth bothering about. So, to the English of it?

Comment: The reason 'neuro' behaves differently to the others in the list is  that whist the other qualifiers are words in themselves, 'neuro' is just a prefix, for words like 'neuroscience', which is not hyphenated. I am not sure if this helps you or not?

Comment: Right, so, I want to know if it's OK to do what I've done in the "possible alternative" there.

Comment: @Jason: Okay, well if you're in a context where your readership recognise all these terns as referring to clearly-distinct "disciplines" then purely for the sake of stylistic "elegance" I would suggest getting the awkward one out of the way first (and set it off from the others with ***comma+and***). *Then* let the specific word ***economics*** propagate leftwords to attach to all preceding terms... *"neuroeconomics, and experimental, behavioral, cognitive, and evolutionary economics."* Just out of interest - is *evolutionary economics* really something different to *evolutionary psychology?*

Comment: @WS2: I'm not sure what you mean by "**'putting on parts' OP**" there. But assuming you're refering to your previous comment, then I think you've absolutely put your finger on why *neuroeconomics* is the awkward "odd man out" here. I actually thought I'd upvoted that comment before posting my second one - but apparently I didn't, so I shall do so now...

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks. I've got a current OP out there, posted tonight about 'putting on parts'. So far only Americans have responded. Interested to hear your views.

Comment: @Jason: In other circumstances I think if this question wasn't actually closed as Primarily Opinion-based, most likely the berst answer you'd get would effectively net down to "It's a stylistic choice; consult you favourite style guide or commissioning editor". I personally think it *is* basically POB/writing advice, but I'm not going to closevote because I think it's interesting.

Answer (score 4):

In its discussion of suspended compounds, *Words Into Type*, third edition (1974), after counseling avoidance of phrases of the type "in- and out-of-school facilities," has this to say:

> Similarly, avoid expressions like the following.
>
> *given and surname*; *cattle and sheepmen*
>
> They should be written:
>
> *given name and surname*; *cattlemen and sheepmen*

The "given and surname" example matches your author's proposed "experimental, behavioral, cognitive, evolutionary, and neuroeconomics" formulation, except in the number of terms involved.

*The Chicago Manual of Style*, 15th edition (2003), is more tolerant of constructions of the type you are considering:

> **7.89** *Hyphen with word space.* When the second part of a hyphenated expression is omitted, the hyphen is retained, followed by a word space. [Examples omitted.] Omission of the second part of a solid compound follows the same pattern.
>
> *both over- and underfed cats*

In Chicago's example, however, both compounds are "solid," whereas in yours, all four of the types of economics identified before *neuroeconomics* are open word pairs. Unfortunately, hyphenating *neuroeconomics* as *neuro-economics* still doesn't put that term on the same footing as the others because they aren't hyphenated compounds any more than they are solid compounds.

If I were dealing with an author who absolutely rejected the obvious approach of repeating the word *economics* in each of the first four terms of the series, I might offer instead the option

> experimental, behavioral, cognitive, neuro-, and evolutionary economics

but really that just amounts to hiding the inconsistency in a slightly less prominent place. You'd be better off going with the wording

> experimental economics, behavioral economics, cognitive economics, evolutionary economics, and neuroeconomics

which has the disadvantage of repetitiveness but the advantage of immediate clarity, or with some revision along the lines of

> experimental, behavioral, cognitive, and evolutionary economics, as well as neuroeconomics

Comment: Thanks, Sven, that's very helpful. The last of your three suggestions is one I had in mind as the best of the 'obviously correct' ways to go. I think I will try that one.