# How to use hyphens appropriately when listing multiple unhyphenated terms?

Tags: american-english, punctuation, hyphenation, suspended-hyphen

Very similiar to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113422/how-to-use-hyphens-appropriately-when-listing-multiple-hyphenated-terms), but with an important difference:

If two words share the same end, but do not contain a hyphen, can I also avoid repeating their ends when listing the words?

How would the following be shortened, considering that *unidirectional* and *bidirectional* do not contain spaces or hyphens?

> To allow unidirectional and bidirectional communication...

In German we would write:

> To allow uni- and bidirectional communication...

MS Word however complains about this, marking "uni" as a spelling error.

Comment: Actually answered by @Sven Yargs at [a suspended hyphen in a list ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/a-suspended-hyphen-in-a-list-with-only-one-hyphenated-word/169775#169775): << In its discussion of suspended compounds, _Words Into Type_, edition 3 (1974), after counseling avoidance of phrases of the type "in- and out-of-school facilities," has this to say: 'Similarly, avoid expressions like the following: _given and surname_ // _cattle and sheepmen_. They should be written: _given name and surname_ // _cattlemen and sheepmen_. >> So it advises against hyphenating.

Comment: I agree with Edwins first comment that his linked question and my linked question are not duplicates and that the asker had the same intention as I had. I also agree with his second comment, that the actual answer to my question is given by Sven Yargs, but to a different question.

Comment: What about the duplicate banner on my question now? By transitivity this would make my question a duplicate of the one I specifically linked as not being a duplicate. How can I improve on this?